# Building Scipy from source in Anaconda using Anaconda Compilers

Tags: python, build, scipy, anaconda, setup.py

I am trying to build `scipy` from source within an Anaconda environment. However during the inplace build, an error is thrown by `ld`.

I create a fresh Anaconda environment, within a fresh Miniconda installation.

```
conda create -n scipy_env
source activate scipy_env
```

I install the `gcc`-related Anaconda compilers as explained in the Anaconda Developer blog [here](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/developer-blog/utilizing-the-new-compilers-in-anaconda-distribution-5/):

```
(scipy_env) conda install gcc_linux-64 gxx_linux-64 gfortran_linux-64
```

I then install `cython`, `atlas`, `openblas`, and `numpy` as required by the *Dependencies* section in the *Scipy Developer Guide* [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/dev/index.html), and the *Building from Source on Linux* page in the *Scipy Reference Guide* [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/building/linux.html):

```
(scipy_env) conda install cython atlas openblas
(scipy_env) conda install numpy
```

I then close the terminal and open a new one and activate the `scipy_env` environment again.

I clone the `scipy` repo into a folder

```
(scipy_env) git clone https://github.com/scipy/scipy.git
(scipy_env) cd ./scipy
```

Finally, I run an inplace build

```
(scipy_env) python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

At one point in during the build, the terminal prints the following. Note that the ellipsis in the middle of the following code block indicates many A4 pages worth of similar terminal output that I have removed for brevity:

```
...

/home/aaron/miniconda3/envs/scipy_env/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-gfortran -Wall -g -Wl,-O2 -Wl,--sort-common -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--disable-new-dtags build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/scipy/fftpack/_fftpackmodule.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/scipy/fftpack/src/zfft.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/scipy/fftpack/src/drfft.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/scipy/fftpack/src/zrfft.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/scipy/fftpack/src/zfftnd.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/scipy/fftpack/src/dct.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/scipy/fftpack/src/dst.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/build/src.linux-x86_64-3.7/scipy/fftpack/fortranobject.o -L/home/aaron/miniconda3/envs/scipy_env/bin/../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/sysroot/lib/../lib -L/home/aaron/miniconda3/envs/scipy_env/bin/../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/sysroot/lib/../lib -Lbuild/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7 -ldfftpack -lfftpack -lgfortran -o scipy/fftpack/_fftpack.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so -Wl,--version-script=build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/link-version-scipy.fftpack._fftpack.map
/home/aaron/miniconda3/envs/scipy_env/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /home/aaron/miniconda3/envs/scipy_env/bin/../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/lib/../lib/Scrt1.o: in function `_start':
/home/rdonnelly/mc/conda-bld/compilers_linux-64_1534865402226/work/.build/src/glibc-2.12.2/csu/../sysdeps/x86_64/elf/start.S:99: undefined reference to `main'
/home/aaron/miniconda3/envs/scipy_env/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/scipy/fftpack/_fftpackmodule.o: in function `f2py_rout__fftpack_destroy_dst1_cache':
_fftpackmodule.c:(.text+0x31): undefined reference to `PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords'
/home/aaron/miniconda3/envs/scipy_env/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: _fftpackmodule.c:(.text+0x3d): undefined reference to `PyErr_Occurred'
/home/aaron/miniconda3/envs/scipy_env/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: _fftpackmodule.c:(.text+0x7b): undefined reference to `Py_BuildValue'
/home/aaron/miniconda3/envs/scipy_env/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/scipy/fftpack/_fftpackmodule.o: in function `f2py_rout__fftpack_destroy_dst2_cache':
_fftpackmodule.c:(.text+0xd1): undefined reference to `PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords'
/home/aaron/miniconda3/envs/scipy_env/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: _fftpackmodule.c:(.text+0xdd): undefined reference to `PyErr_Occurred'

...

/home/aaron/miniconda3/envs/scipy_env/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: fortranobject.c:(.text+0x21f8): undefined reference to `PyOS_snprintf'
/home/aaron/miniconda3/envs/scipy_env/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/build/src.linux-x86_64-3.7/scipy/fftpack/fortranobject.o: in function `F2PyCapsule_AsVoidPtr':
fortranobject.c:(.text+0x2238): undefined reference to `PyCapsule_GetPointer'
/home/aaron/miniconda3/envs/scipy_env/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: fortranobject.c:(.text+0x2257): undefined reference to `PyErr_Clear'
/home/aaron/miniconda3/envs/scipy_env/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/build/src.linux-x86_64-3.7/scipy/fftpack/fortranobject.o: in function `F2PyCapsule_Check':
fortranobject.c:(.text+0x2273): undefined reference to `PyCapsule_Type'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: Command "/home/aaron/miniconda3/envs/scipy_env/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-gfortran -Wall -g -Wl,-O2 -Wl,--sort-common -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--disable-new-dtags build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/scipy/fftpack/_fftpackmodule.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/scipy/fftpack/src/zfft.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/scipy/fftpack/src/drfft.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/scipy/fftpack/src/zrfft.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/scipy/fftpack/src/zfftnd.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/scipy/fftpack/src/dct.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/scipy/fftpack/src/dst.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/build/src.linux-x86_64-3.7/scipy/fftpack/fortranobject.o -L/home/aaron/miniconda3/envs/scipy_env/bin/../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/sysroot/lib/../lib -L/home/aaron/miniconda3/envs/scipy_env/bin/../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/sysroot/lib/../lib -Lbuild/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7 -ldfftpack -lfftpack -lgfortran -o scipy/fftpack/_fftpack.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so -Wl,--version-script=build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/link-version-scipy.fftpack._fftpack.map" failed with exit status 1
```

I do not have any knowledge about C and Fortran compilation, so I have no idea as to what is causing the error to be thrown in the block above, or more importantly what to do to fix it.

Does anyone have any advice as to how to deal with this problem?

Comment: I have run into the same problem, and it is clear to me that ld can not find any python references. PyCapsule_Type is really just the tip of the iceberg....
I went and hardcoded in a link to libpython3.7m.so but that didn't seem to help. This is bothersome because nm -g clearly shows the PyCapsule_Type method.